# Very ample divisor on elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, elliptic-curves, schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $1$ in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$(elliptic curve) , and $P,Q$ be two distinct points over $X$. I want to ask if there exists a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ which intersects $X$ exactly at $P,Q$.

My rough idea is that the divisor $2P+2Q$ is very ample, hence by definition there exists a closed imbedding $i: X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $i^*{\mathcal{O}(1)}\cong\mathcal{O}(-2P-2Q)$, then $i^*x_k\in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(-2P-2Q))$, which is to say $i^*x_k(\forall k=0,...,n-1)$ is a function over $X$ vanishing at $P,Q$. But there may exist other zeros of $i^*x_k$. I don't know how to continue.

Could someone give an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you don't count multiplicity. A line could be tangent at $\,P\,$ and intersect at $\,Q\,$ as in point doubling.

Comment: For general $P,Q$ there is no such curve .

Comment: @Mohan I am not sure, but you can see the comments of user auniket's answer of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133470/affine-open-subset-of-affine-scheme/133474#133474).

Comment: @Somos But the tangent line at $P$ may not pass $Q$?

Comment: For general $P,Q$ and an inflection point $O$, $P-O, Q-O$ will be linearly independent in the Picard group and then there will be no such curve.